# Storing, modifying and manipulating web scraped data

Tags: python

I'm working on a python webscraper that pulls data from a car advertising site. I got the scraping part all done with beatifoulsoup but I've ran into many difficulties trying to store and modify it. I would really appreciate some advice on this part since I'm a lacking knowledge on this part.

So here is what I want to do:

1. Scrape the data each hour (done).
2. Store scraped data as a dictionary in a .JSON file (done).
3. Everytime the ad_link not found in the scraped_data.json set it to dict['Status'] = 'Inactive' (done).
4. If a cars price changes , print notification + add old price to dictionary. On this part I came across many challenges with the .JSON way.

I've kept using 2 .json files and comparing them to each other (scraped_data_temp , permanent_data.json) but I think this is by far not the best method.

What would you guys suggest? How should I do this? .

What would be the best way to approach manipulating this kind of data ? (Databases maybe? - got no experince with them but I'm eager to learn) and what would be a good way to represent this kind of data, pygal?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would suggest using a database. sqlite is basic but extremely easy to work with and python has built-in support for it

Comment: I would definitely look into it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have larger data, I would definitely recommend using some kind of DB. If you don't have the need to use DB server, you can use sqlite. I have used it in the past to save bigger data locally. You can use [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) in python to interact with DB-s.

As for displaying data, I tend to use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). It's extremely flexible, has extensive documentation and examples, so you can adjust data to you linking, graphs, charts, etc.

I'm assuming that you are using python3.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. My data is not very large (at most 10 cars at a time) . My Issue is modifying the current data, and what would be the best approach . Like I said at the moment I'm using 2 json files and comparing them to each other but I really feel this aproach is bad.